# Why jQuery is not working for mobile filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

In mobile view, i have the set of filters set to `display: none;`
and im trying to use jQuery's `.toggle` function to display and hide those filters, but for some reason my jQuery is not working and nothing happens when i click the filter button.

HTML:

```
    <p class="block-subtitle block-subtitle--filter" onclick="javascript:toggleDiv('narrow-by-list');"><?php echo $this->__('Filter') ?></p>
    <dl id="narrow-by-list">
        <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
        <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
        <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

function toggleDiv(divId) {

   $("#"+divId).toggle();

}
</script>
```

You can test here (must view in mobile (<767px wide browser)):
http://180fragrances.com/index.php/kentucky-derby-hats-women

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `jQuery.noConflict()`, Jquery "frees" the `$` variable so it can be used by other framweworks (like prototype in this case).
So `$` references the prototype object.

you need to use `jQuery("#"+divId).toggle();` to make it work.